# MVC3 Routing - remove param

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm getting 2 params on my URL but i would like
to **hide** one (as I don't really need it).

What would be the easiest way?

My current routing looks like this:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Product",
                "{Name}",
                new { controller = "Catalog", action = "ProductByName" },
                new[] { "MyController" });
```

How can I hide any other param that comes on the URL ?
By hiding i mean not displaying it on the URL itself.

If hiding is NOT an option allowed on Routing,
how would i redirect the call from the Routing module ?

Comment: I think you have to make a redirection to hide the param you dislike.

Comment: @gdoron Do you have a sample on how to do that at the routing level ?

Comment: I added an answer with it. tough I wouldn't use it. Why do you need it? url is just a link and the second param isn't so bad IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to alter/rewrite the url. I found [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) which might help you. Or, if performance is not that a big a deal, then you can do a redirect.

Comment: That's more for ASPX apps, not MVC3 I think

Comment: differences between aspx vs razor doen't really have anything to do with the solution...the example is using HttpContext.RewritePath(...) which is accessible pretty much all across ASP.NET...really shouldn't have a problem

Answer (score 0):

In the action redirect to the new url

```
return Redirect(/*... your's params.*/);
```

You must be aware of the low performance this is causing, each HTTP request becomes two.
Think twice if this is really what you need and want.

Comment: I agree ...that's not the type of solution i was thinking. I was more hoping to discover a conceptual routing redirect :--)